# Juntar ou ajuntar?

Tags: verbos

Qual o termo correto: juntar ou ajuntar?

Parece que o termo "ajuntar" só é utilizado na língua falada, e é cada vez mais utilizado. Mas ele é correto ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pelo dicionário são [**sinónimos**](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/juntar-ou-ajuntar/) ou equivalentes e ambos corretos.

### [a.jun.tar](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ajuntar)

> ### [ɐʒũˈtar]
>
> #### verbo transitivo
>
> 1. juntar; aproximar; unir; ligar
> 2. agrupar; reunir
> 3. acrescentar
> 4. economizar, amealhar
>
> #### verbo pronominal
>
> 1. juntar-se; unir-se
> 2. agrupar-se; reunir-se
> 3. *popular* tornar-se amante de

### [jun.tar](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/juntar)

> ### [ʒũˈtar]
>
> #### verbo transitivo
>
> 1. unir; aproximar; pôr junto
> 2. fazer encontrar ao mesmo tempo no mesmo local; reunir; agrupar
> 3. misturar
> 4. acrescentar; adicionar; incluir
> 5. acumular
> 6. estabelecer ligação entre
> 7. alisar com a junteira (as extremidades das tábuas que se hão de sobrepor)
>
> #### verbo pronominal
>
> 1. unir-se; aproximar-se; ficar junto
> 2. encontrar-se ao mesmo tempo no mesmo local; reunir-se; agrupar-se
> 3. associar-se; aliar-se
> 4. misturar-se
> 5. *popular* passar a viver maritalmente, sem casar

Answer (score 2):

> As palavras *juntar* e *ajuntar* existem na língua portuguesa e estão corretas: são palavras sinônimas.
>
> Podemos utilizar os verbos *juntar* ou *ajuntar* sempre que quisermos referir o ato de pôr junto, acrescentar, organizar segundo critérios, colar, cozer, recolher, acumular, colecionar, amealhar dinheiro, unir-se, cruzar animais e atacar com violência.
>
> Há uma maior preferência pela utilização do verbo *juntar*, que é considerado o mais correto e socialmente aceite pelos falantes. O verbo *ajuntar* é considerado informal, sendo utilizado numa linguagem mais simples.

[Fonte](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/juntar-ou-ajuntar/)